# Simultaneous two player mode

Tags: wii-u, skylanders-giants

I bought Skylanders Giants for my kids and they've done something to make it so that in two player mode they can't play at the same time, something they've been able to do before. They press the `-` button on either the Wii U gamepad or Wii controller to swap to the other player. How can I make it simultaneous two player again?

Comment: read the instruction manual?

Comment: I have read both the leaflet inside the case and also the online manual. No such luck. As stated, this was working per the instructions, but what I've described (`in two player mode they can't play at the same time`) is not detailed in either. Do you have anything useful or constructive to suggest?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [*Skylanders Giants* Wii U manual](http://www.skylanders.com/content/dam/atvi/skylanders/giants/manuals/SG_WiiU_Manual_OnLine_FINAL2.pdf):

> **CO-OP PLAY**
>   At any time during Story Mode, a second player can join the game by hitting the A Button on their Wii Remote, **and placing a Skylander on  the Portal of Power**. To drop out of the game, Player 1 or Player 2 must  remove their Skylander from the Portal of Power and press the B Button  on their Wii Remote.

(Emphasis mine).

I would assume what happens is they don't have two Skylanders on the portal, so they just switch control on a single Skylander between the two controllers.

Comment: Must resist smart alec comment.... Failed.

Answer (score 0):

When we could not add the second player to Skylanders Swap Force we had to exit the game. Then went to the Wii Main Menu prior to selecting the game and added the second remote controller. Then we were able to add the second player while in the game as outlined above by pressing A then placing character that he portal. We could not get a second player on Giants either but maybe now it might work too.

Answer (score -1):

The problem might be the Nunchuck. We had the same problem, then we replaced the Nunchuck, and it fixed this issue.

Answer (score -2):

You have to connect the nunchuck to be able to play. If you don't do it, it fails.